# Rails - get the model name for a view_context

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a class that receives a view_context as a param for its constructor. I would like to get the model which that view_context is associated. Made a quick search and didn't found it... thanks!

Comment: what model would you expect to find in the view_context? are you thinking of `@user` for something like user/show?

Comment: I call the constructor of the class on my index action, and pass the view_context as argument. So, if I am doin' that on users controller, for example, I would like to know that the view_context I received on my class belongs to User model. Sorry if I didn't made it clear

Comment: what hinders you from passing the actual model via the constructor? that sounds like a cleaner solution to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. From view_context, did it this way:

```
view_context.controller.controller_path.classify.constantize
```

So I could get the name of the columns for that model. Thanks!